# How to debug 400 Invalid P-Asserted-Identity?

Tags: java, android, sip

How can I debug this 400 response resulted after an INVITE request and 100 TRYING result?

```
I/SIP_MESSAGE_OUT( 1307): Message being sent(TcpChannel):
I/SIP_MESSAGE_OUT( 1307): ---------------------------------------------y>>>>
I/SIP_MESSAGE_OUT( 1307): INVITE sip:***@***.***;user=phone SIP/2.0
...
I/SIP_MESSAGE_IN( 1307): Incoming message():
I/SIP_MESSAGE_IN( 1307): ---------------------------------------------y<<<<
I/SIP_MESSAGE_IN( 1307): SIP/2.0 100 Trying 
...
I/SIP_MESSAGE_IN( 1307): Incoming message():
I/SIP_MESSAGE_IN( 1307): ---------------------------------------------y<<<<
I/SIP_MESSAGE_IN( 1307): SIP/2.0 400 Invalid P-Asserted-Identity 
...
```

Can't find anything regarding this 400 status code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

400 SIP error response means ·Bad request", you can find a list of SIP responses in this [Wikidepia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_response_codes#4xx.E2.80.94Client_Failure_Responses)

Most strange thing here is that, your network is complaining about your asserted identity but, this header, is added by [P-CSCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Multimedia_Subsystem) server an not by the UA(this means that this should not be you fault). Is it possible that you're working with OpenIMS solution? I mean, there's a know miss configuration issue with OpenIMS (please, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20011061/1419134) answer) that P-CSCF is not listening in SIP standard port (5060) but in 4060, causing some problems with, exactly, P-Asserted-Identity header.

If this is the case, you would need to point your application to port 4060 and try again. If you don't really know, it may be interesting to try.